# Easiest way to duplicate categories in magento with magmi import/export extension

Tags: magento

I m using magmi import export it works quite good to import category but i wont to duplicate category with csv file and insert into another root category, Here is my **import.csv** but its not working

[image]

Any other suggestion to duplicate categories will be appreciated